# How to fill Primefaces Autocomplete from Managed Bean

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I have a primefaces autocomplete which is shown below:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{consultaEventoCargoMBean.idUaSelecionada}" completeMethod="#{consultaEventoCargoMBean.completeUADestino}" var="ua" itemLabel="#{ua.name}" itemValue="#{ua.id}" forceSelection="false" appendTo="@this" />
```

Where `idUaSelecionada` and `ua.id` are Integer and `ua.name` is a String.

My issue is when I load my page to update the data. My `idUaSelecionada` is already filled and a object ready to be passed as suggestion (it would be a list of a only element). I was not able to find a way to fill this autocomplete - at least the text component.

Reading the Autocomplete souce code, I saw that there is a List called `suggestions`. Although there is not a setter for this list, it has a getter. But if I try something like `autocomplete.getSuggestions().add(...)` I get a `NullPointerException`. The only way I found to fill this list is through the method indicated by `completeMethod` tag attribute, who receives a String and returns a List.

I was not able to find in internet how to fill this List. That's why I am  asking this to see if anyone has any answers.

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: Tried using `setSuggetions(...)`?

Comment: There is no setter for suggestions. See https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.2/org/primefaces/component/autocomplete/AutoComplete.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to trigger execution of method defined in `completeMethod` tag attribute and load suggestion(s).

Supposing that you want to do it when page loads, add this script to your page

```
<script>
    function triggerSuggestionLoading() {
          //finds autocomplete input text field
          var autocomplete = document.getElementsByClassName('ui-autocomplete-input')[0];

          //sets autocomplete query, for example
          autocomplete.value="test";

          //simulates key press triggering completeMethod to be executed
          autocomplete.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
          autocomplete.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
          autocomplete.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));

          //sets focus on autocomplete
          autocomplete.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus'));

          //clears autocomplete text
          autocomplete.value="";
     }

     window.onload = function() {
         triggerSuggestionLoading();
     };
</script>
```

Actually whenever you refresh your suggestion list and want to load suggestions into `p:autocomplete` just call `triggerSuggestionLoading()` method at the end (after all procedures are finished).

I've tested it in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the approach in this autocomplete, so I will not use your advice. But anyway, I hope that it can be useful for anyone else.